# Opentk shows out of memory exception - OPENGL

Tags: c#, opengl, out-of-memory, glsl, opentk

I'm completely new to [openGL](https://www.opengl.org/).

I have to show two images side by side using shader code.

It shows properly using below code. But throws an

> out of memory

exception and the entire system gets hangs.

Can you please check my code to see what might be the cause?

I think the problem is that I'm not properly deallocating memory from openTK textures after I don't need them, so I'm generating massive amounts of images, but I don't know how to fix this.

```
 public partial class Form7ImageOnly : Form
{       
    string file = "opentksquare.png";
    string file1 = "img_smile.png";
    int program;
    int vertShader;
    int fragShader;
    int buffer;
    int positionLocation;
    int positionLocation1;
    int positionLocation2;
    int texture;
    int texture1;
    int ScreenWidth;
    int ScreenHeight;
    float[] vertices = {
            // Left bottom triangle
            -1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, -1f, 0f,
            1f, 1f, 0f,
            // Right top triangle
            1f, 1f, 0f,
              -1f, 1f, 0f,
             -1f, -1f, 0f
    };

    public Form7ImageOnly()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form7ImageOnly_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        glControl.Resize += new EventHandler(glControl_Resize);
        glControl.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(glControl_Paint);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);
        Application.Idle += Application_Idle;
        glControl_Resize(glControl, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    void Application_Idle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (glControl.IsIdle)
        {
            Render();
        }
    }
    private void Render()
    {
        ScreenWidth = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        ScreenHeight = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        glControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight);//full screen
        texture = LoadTexture(file);
        texture1 = LoadTexture(file1);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        DrawImage(texture,texture1);
    }
    private void glControl_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Render();
    }

    private void glControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Init();
    }
    private void Init()
    {
        CreateShaders();
        CreateProgram();
        InitBuffers();
    }
    public void DrawImage(int image,int image1)
    {
        GL.Viewport(new Rectangle(0, 0,  ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight));
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        GL.PushMatrix();
        GL.LoadIdentity();
        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Lighting);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);

        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture0);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image);
        GL.Uniform1(positionLocation1, 0);
        GL.ActiveTexture(TextureUnit.Texture1);
        GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, image1);
        GL.Uniform1(positionLocation2, 1);
        RunShaders();

        //GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Quads);
        //GL.TexCoord2(0, 1);
        //GL.Vertex3(0, 0, 0);
        //GL.TexCoord2(1, 1);
        //GL.Vertex3(1920, 0, 0);
        //GL.TexCoord2(1, 0);
        //GL.Vertex3(1920, 1080, 0);
        //GL.TexCoord2(0, 0);
        //GL.Vertex3(0, 1080, 0);
        //GL.End();

        GL.Disable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
        GL.PopMatrix();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
        GL.PopMatrix();
        GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
            System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();
        glControl.SwapBuffers();
    }
    private void RunShaders()
    {

        GL.ClearColor(Color.Violet);
        GL.UseProgram(program);
        GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, vertices.Length / 3);
        ErrorCode ec = GL.GetError();
        if (ec != 0)
        System.Console.WriteLine(ec.ToString());
        Console.Read();
    }
    private void CreateProgram()
    {
        program = GL.CreateProgram();
        GL.AttachShader(program, vertShader);
        GL.AttachShader(program, fragShader);
        GL.LinkProgram(program);
    }

    private void CreateShaders()
    {
        /***********Vert Shader********************/
        vertShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(vertShader, @"attribute vec3 a_position;
                                    varying vec2 vTexCoord;
                                    void main() {
                                    vTexCoord = (a_position.xy + 1) / 2;
                                    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1);
                                    }");
        GL.CompileShader(vertShader);


        /***********Frag Shader ****************/
        fragShader = GL.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
        GL.ShaderSource(fragShader, @"precision highp float;
    uniform sampler2D sTexture;uniform sampler2D sTexture1;
  uniform int screenwidth;
                                   varying vec2 vTexCoord;
                             void main ()
                             {

         if ( vTexCoord.x<0.5 )
         gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture, vec2(vTexCoord.x*2.0, vTexCoord.y));
         else
         gl_FragColor = texture2D (sTexture1, vec2(1.0- (vTexCoord.x*2.0-1.0), vTexCoord.y));
                             }");
        GL.CompileShader(fragShader);
    }
    private void InitBuffers()
    {
        buffer = GL.GenBuffer();
        positionLocation = GL.GetAttribLocation(program, "a_position");
        positionLocation1 = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexture");
        positionLocation2 = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "sTexture1");
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
        GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, buffer);
        GL.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)(vertices.Length * sizeof(float)), vertices, BufferUsageHint.StaticDraw);
        GL.VertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 3, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, 0,0);
    }

    public int LoadTexture(string file)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(file);
        int tex = -1;
        if (bitmap != null)
        {
            GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref tex);
            GL.Hint(HintTarget.PerspectiveCorrectionHint, HintMode.Nicest);
            GL.GenTextures(1, out tex);
            GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, tex);
            bitmap.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
            BitmapData data = bitmap.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            GL.TexImage2D(TextureTarget.Texture2D, 0, PixelInternalFormat.Rgba,data.Width,data.Height, 0,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
            bitmap.UnlockBits(data);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMagFilter, (int)TextureMagFilter.Linear);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapS, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);
            GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.ClampToEdge);

        }
        return tex;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you `LoadTexture` in every frame?

Comment: yes.Is that the issue?

Comment: You create a new texture object on the GPU in every frame `GL.GenTextures(1, out tex);` and you never delete it. You spam the GPU with equal texture objects. Note `GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref tex);` deletes always -1, so it does nothing.

Comment: ohh ok! so how can i delete it ?

Comment: Why do you want to delete it? Don't do that in every frame. It is sufficient to load the textures once in `Init`. But `GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref texture);` and `GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref texture1);` would do what you want.

Comment: ok will load the textures once in Init, and where should I write this lines GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref texture);  GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref texture1); ?

Comment: If you load the textures in `Init()`, then you don't need it at the moment.

Comment: To confirm what you said : If I call it in Render() the code should be like : GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref texture); texture = LoadTexture(file);
    GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref texture1)  ;  texture1 = LoadTexture(file1); And no need of line    GL.DeleteTextures(1, ref tex); in LoadTexture(). Is'nt it?

Comment: Yes it is, this should work